# How to pass parameter of object type from ajax call to mvc action

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a following action method

```
 public JsonResult DeleteRecord(string tableName, string fieldName, object id, string configs, string extenderName = null){}
```

I am calling it from ajax call like this .

```
 var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Dynamic/DeleteRecord?tableName=" + tableName + "&id=" + id + "&fieldName=" + colName + "&extenderName=" + extndname
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        if (data.Success == true) {
          
        } else {
    
        }
    })
    .fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    })
    .always(function() {});
```

I am receiving all the parameters on my backend but not receiving the id as int it is showing `{object}`

Comment: if you expect id as int why it is object in your action method?

Answer (score 0):

**1. You can try with this example for pass object in ajax call**

```
    var updateModel = new Object();
        updateModel.name = name;
        updateModel.address = address;
        updateModel.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",           
        url: "@(Url.Action("UpdateStudent", "Student"))",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(updateModel),          
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "Suceess") {
                window.location.href = "";
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });

    public JsonResult UpdateStudent(UpdateModel updateModel)
    {
        process = "Suceess";
        return Json(process, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```